# Wave Propagation: Dipole Antenna

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, dipole, antennas

I was watching the following video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZaXm6wau-jc). This video explains the following image below represents an electric field generated from a dipole antenna. How does a single wave of electromagnetic radiation look in context to the picture below?

[image]

**I understand that the electric field and magnetic look like this where their cross product gives the direction where the wave propagates. **

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnetic field lines are circles around the polar axis.
This magnetic field is strongest near the equatorial plane
weakest near the polar axis.

The image below (from an excellent animation at [Dipole Radiation -
Chair of Physics Education - LMU Munich](https://www.en.didaktik.physik.uni-muenchen.de/multimedia/dipolstrahlung/index.html))
shows the electric field (in blue/green) and the
magnetic field (in red/orange) of an oscillating electric dipole.

[image: dipole radiation]

Electric field ($\vec{E}$) and magnetic field ($\vec{B}$) are
perpendicular to each other. And their cross product
($\vec{E}\times\vec{B}$) is pointing outwards from the central point.